# Accessing MS Teams via Graph API using unlicensed admin

Tags: microsoft-teams

We're trying to access MS Teams (apps : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/_teams_guid_/installedApps?$expand=teamsAppusing`) using unlicensed admin and getting next error :
"Admin Login. Teams is disabled in user licenses". What does this error means (googling didn't provide too much info) ? is this means that admin need to be licensed ? or it's something else ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using Application permission or Delegated permissions? Is Admin part of the team (_team_for_guid_)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT we're using Application permissions and admin is part of the team and even more, it's part of the channel (we add it if it's not part of the channel). Thanks

Comment: @SlavaG we have raised a bug for this and it is being investigated. Thanks!!